# What exactly is A. A. Robb's version of "the result first proved by Robb (1936)"?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, spacetime, specific-reference, metric-space

Considering four distinct events in a spacetime region in which values of [Synge's world function $\sigma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synge%27s_world_function) are defined (up to a common non-zero factor) for each pair of events,
and specificly considering

- three events $\mathcal A$, $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal Q$ which are straight wrt. each other, i.e. in terms of the values of Synge's world function

$$ 0 = \begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal P \, ] & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal Q \, ] \\ 1 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal P \, ] & 0 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal P, \, \mathcal Q \, ] \\ 1 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal Q \, ] & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal P, \, \mathcal Q \, ] & 0 \end{vmatrix}, $$

and a fourth event $\mathcal B$ such that

- events $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal P$ are lightlike related to each other, i.e. $\sigma[ \, \, \mathcal B, \, \mathcal P \, ] = 0$,
- events $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal Q$ are lightlike related to each other, i.e. $\sigma[ \, \, \mathcal B, \, \mathcal Q \, ] = 0$, and
- all four events are flat (or more correctly, of course: plane) wrt. each other, i.e.

$$ 0 = \begin{vmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal B \, ] & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal P \, ] & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal Q \, ] \\ 1 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal B \, ] & 0 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal B, \, \mathcal P \, ] & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal B, \, \mathcal Q \, ] \\ 1 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal P \, ]  & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal B, \, \mathcal P \, ] & 0 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal P, \, \mathcal Q \, ] \\ 1 & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal Q \, ] & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal B, \, \mathcal Q \, ] & \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal P, \, \mathcal Q \, ] & 0 \end{vmatrix},$$

then (as follows by explicit calculation):

- either event $\mathcal A$ is between events $\mathcal P$ and $\mathcal Q$, i.e. (consistent with the straightness-relation above):
  $\sigma[ \, \, \mathcal P, \, \mathcal Q \, ] =  \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal P \, ] + \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal Q \, ] + 2 \, \sqrt{ \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal P \, ] \, \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal Q \, ] } $,
  and
  $$ \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal B \, ] = -\sqrt{ \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal P \, ] \, \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal Q \, ] } \, \left( \text{Sgn}[ \, \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal P, \, \mathcal Q \, ] \, ] \right), \tag{*} $$
- or otherwise:
  $$ \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal B \, ] = \sqrt{ \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal P \, ] \, \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal A, \, \mathcal Q \, ] } \, \left( \text{Sgn}[ \, \sigma[ \, \, \mathcal P, \, \mathcal Q \, ] \, ] \right). \tag{**} $$

Equations $(*)$ or $(**)$, in various choices of "language" and notation, are "[here](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22coordinate+free+language+%28Robb+1936%29%22) and [there](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22robb%27s+theorem%22+%22%281936%29%22)" attributed to [A. A. Robb, *A Theory of Time and Space* (1936)](https://archive.org/details/geometryoftimean032218mbp/page/n7/mode/2up).

**My question:**
Exactly which (outright) theorem, or which (supplementary) formula, in Robb's book corresponds to either equation $(*)$, or $(**)$, or to both ?

Comment: The text you link to is actually [Robb, A Theory of Time and Space (1914)](https://archive.org/details/theoryoftimespac00robbuoft/page/n7/mode/2up).  This is [Robb, _Geometry of Time and Space_ (1936)](https://archive.org/details/geometryoftimean032218mbp/page/n7/mode/2up)

Comment: @Paul T.: _"The text you link to is actually [...] (1914)"_ -- Oh my goodness! Sorry! (Too many tabs open !?! ...). I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of notation in Robb (1936) to sift through.
So far, I have been unable able to spot the **two-times formula**.

However, the **two-times formula** for the square-interval can be seen here in
Robb's (1911) Optical Geometry of Motion
( https://archive.org/details/opticalgeometryo00robbrich )
from page 6

> *[on page 5, Robb defines $N_d$ the "index of departure"
> and $N_r$ the "index of return".]*
>
> We shall define the *distance* of any particle P from A as measured by
> $$\frac{N_r -N_d}{2}.$$
>
> In our permanent system this quantity remains fixed for each particle.
> If then we select any particle $P$, and let
> $$\frac{N_r -N_d}{2}=k,$$
> we have
> $$N_r N_d= \left(\frac{N_r +N_d}{2}\right)^2 -k^2.$$

and then on page 8 appears this figure:
[image: Robb-1911-p.8]

(Interesting...
but I don't expect to find the
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Menger_determinant
and https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html
in Robb's work.)

[By the way, I think this 1911 work is where "rapidity" gets its name from.]

Comment: robphy: _"here in Robb's (1911) Optical Geometry of Motion"_ -- Very nice! +1. _"a lot of notation in Robb (1936) to sift through."_ -- No kidding! Moreover: [It's worthwhile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/696164)! (Isn't the OP question thus  a reasonably good question?? ... Just kidding!) _"the **two-times formula**"_ -- Where does this name come from? _"but I don't expect to find the Cayley-Menger determinant in Robb's work"_ -- But Robb deals with "straightness", "planarity", "flatness"! ... (Also, like [Cayley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Cayley), he worked at Cambridge.)

Comment: @user12262 I call it the two-times formula because it's a radar measurement using two time-intervals. I learned the formula from Geroch's "General Relativity from A to B". It turns out it's related to the area of a causal diamond of AB, as I used in my article 
"Relativity on rotated graph paper"
American Journal of Physics 84, 344 (2016); https://doi.org/10.1119/1.4943251 .

Comment: robphi: _"I call it the two-times formula [...]"_ -- I call it a special case of [Stewart's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stewart%27s_theorem). (Cmp. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4066114/277973) to [_"Generalizing Stewart's theorem to timelike triangles in Lorentzian spaces of constant curvature"_ (mse/q/4066114)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4029996/277973) p.s. the [Cayley-Menger-experssion for volume (of tetrahedra, and simplices in general)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume) was (allegedly; MTW, footnote of "Box 13.1") known to Tartaglia.